# Dynamic data loading in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a google chart which I am feeding with JSON data as follows:

```
      var visualization;
      var chart_url = 'http://XXappspot.com/data?v=load1&v=load5&v=load15&span=100';

      function drawVisualization() {
        var query = new google.visualization.Query(chart_url);
        query.send(handleQueryResponse);
      }

      function handleQueryResponse(response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
          alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
          return;
        }

        var data = response.getDataTable();
        var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat( { pattern: 'd MMM, HH:mm:ss' } );
        formatter.format(data, 0);
        visualization = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
        visualization.draw(data, { hAxis: { format: "HH:mm" }});
      }

      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

Now I would like to add buttons on the page which will change the data source (request other data) and refresh the chart. I have seen the use of controls in the documentation but they seem to work only with data already downloaded, while I would like to re-download different data. Any ideas how to do this?

Bonus question: is there a way to change the timezone of the X axis? No, adding "timeZone" to the hAxis options does not work. Preferably, I would like to show datetime data in the local timezone of the user.

Comment: wouldn't be much simple if you will create a function to fill the data which get as param you json? and each time you want to reinit it just recall your ajax handler and call again the draw chart function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an event listener to the buttons on your page that changes `chart_url` and calls `drawVisualization`.

```
function changeUrl () {
    chart_url = 'http://new.url.com';
    drawVisualization();
}
```

As far as changing the timezone of the data, by default the Date objects are created and displayed in the local timezone.  If your data represents another timezone, you must enter it as UTC time, or use a function to convert the dates to UTC time:

```
function drawCharts () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date and time');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');

    // add 100 rows of pseudo-random-walk data
    var val = 50, hour, minute;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        val += ~~(Math.random() * 5) * Math.pow(-1, ~~(Math.random() * 2));
        if (val < 0) {
            val += 5;
        }
        else if (val > 100) {
            val -= 5;
        }
        data.addRow([new Date(2013, 0, 1, i), val]);
    }

    // the time entered was supposed to be UTC time, but is entered as local time
    // this function updates the Date objects to the proper UTC time
    function localDateToUTCDate (d) {
        d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - d.getTimezoneOffset());
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        data.setValue(i, 0, localDateToUTCDate(data.getValue(i, 0)));
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        containerId: 'chart_div',
        dataTable: data,
        options: {
            height: 400,
            width: 600,
            vAxis: {
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 100
            }
        }
    });
    chart.draw();
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['controls'], callback: drawCharts});
```

see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/4vDVn/

Comment: Thanks, changing the url works fine. However considering the dates, I am sending the data from a GMT+1 timezone in epoch to the server for storage, storing it in ndb.DateTimeProperty (looking at it on the server via , it seems to be stored in UTC) and sending it to the browser as Date(). In the JSON sent to the browser, it is definitely a Date object with UTC parameters (e.g. `"v":"Date(2013,11,19,15,59,51,415)"`). Based on what you wrote, it should be automatically converted to the browser's timezone i.e. GMT+1, but no, they are shown in UTC, both on the chart and on the horizontal axis.

Comment: The Date gets created as a local date unless you explicitly specify otherwise.  Given that you are using the Visualization API's custom string-to-Date format, I don't think you can specify otherwise, so you have to use a conversion function like the one I put in my answer.

Comment: OK, so I understand now that when a Date object is created from the output, the parameters are considered as local time instead of UTC. However they are in UTC (and I believe it is best practice to store and transfer dates always in UTC), so I would have to shift them to local time. Since it is a quite complex DataTable for Google Charts, are there any predefined functions which would process the dates and transform them into the browser's local time? I understand your suggestion but I would hope that there is already something premade for this so I do not have to deepdive into the DataTable.

Comment: You don't have to deep dive.  Use the `DataTable#getValue` and `DataTable#setValue` methods to get and set cell values.  You can get a row count to loop over the table's rows with `DataTable#getNumberOfRows`.  I'll update my code with an example.

Answer (score 0):

So given the problem that the dates are stored on the server and transmitted to the client in UTC, whereas the client interprets the UTC data as local time, the solution is to process the JSON-fed DataTable on the client side so that the input parameters to date are correctly considered as UTC:

```
// shift dates (1st column) to local timezone
for (var y = 0, maxrows = data.getNumberOfRows(); y < maxrows; y++) {
  var d = data.getValue(y, 0);
  d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - d.getTimezoneOffset());
  data.setValue(y, 0, d)
}
```